# How to evaluate an input in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting an input in one of my variables and basically I want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE
WHERE 
     IF @INPUT = 1
         ITEMID = 16 OR ITEMID = 13
     ELSE IF @INPUT = 2
         ITEMID = 11 OR ITEMID = 14
     ELSE
         ITEMID = 0
```

Is there a way to do this, please forgive if this is wrong but I wanted to portray my issue as easily understandable as possible.

I tried with CASE before this like

```
WHERE 
    CASE @INPUT
       WHEN 1 THEN ITEMID = 16 OR ITEMID = 13
       WHEN 2 THEN ITEMID = 11 OR ITEMID = 14
       ELSE ITEMID = 0
    END
```

But all of these approaches throw errors, I would appreciate a good advise, more efficient way to do this if possible.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Generally I would try to avoid hard-coding IDs like that in a query. Is there something special about 13 and 16, or about 11 and 14? Could they be a category or a group on their own? Perhaps your table needs a new column to identify groups of elements -- you could simplify your query that way. Think about it in terms of maintenance -- are you really going to want to maintain those hard-coded IDs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 WHERE (@INPUT = 1 AND ITEMID IN (13,16)) 
    OR (@INPUT = 2 AND ITEMID IN (11,14))
    OR (@INPUT NOT IN (1,2) AND ITEMID = 0)
```

Comment: That was surprisingly hard to type on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another answer..

```
WHERE (@INPUT in (1,2) AND ITEMID+2*@INPUT IN (15,18))
OR (@INPUT NOT IN (1,2) AND ITEMID = 0)
```

or

```
WHERE (@INPUT in (1,2) AND ITEMID IN (15-2*@INPUT,18-2*@INPUT))
OR (@INPUT NOT IN (1,2) AND ITEMID = 0)
```

Works because when `@input = 1`:

- `if ITEMID = 13, ITEMID + 2*1 = 15`
- `if ITEMID = 16, ITEMID + 2*1 = 18`

and when `@input = 2`:

- `if ITEMID = 11, ITEMID + 2*2 = 15`
- `if ITEMID = 14, ITEMID + 2*2 = 18`

But you should never use this, unless you intentionally want to obscure your code!

Comment: Works - but try to maintain / fix that code eight months from now.... not even *YOU* will remember what the heck that code was all about .....

Comment: Hence my comment that this should never be used, although the second option I just added (which is even less readable) is probably more efficient :)

Comment: Agree with @marc_s, but if performance is an issue and this trick does help, I don't see why it can't be used if there's no faster alternative. *But* this kind of code just **ought to be commented** (for instance, a more readable version of the filter could be specified to give subsequent maintainers the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Not to obfuscate the issue TOO much, but I will just quickly point out that in my view Cory, when he suggests a new column, is on the right track, but I can understand that you don't always have the freedom to change your data structures.

However, if I can't change my data structures I'd still prefer to have my SELECT statement made in such a way as though I did have the perfect structure to work from.

For this I tend to use APPLY to add an extra derived column to which I can refer in my WHERE or SELECT clauses.

Eg:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM People p
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN p.ItemID IN (13,16) THEN 1
                WHEN p.ItemID IN (11,14) THEN 2
                ELSE 0
            END        AS ItemCode
    ) pInfo
WHERE
    @Input = pInfo.ItemCode
```

But really I just like using CROSS APPLY too much.

This does have the advantage that if you ever want to re-use that conditional logic (for example by adding `SELECT pInfo.ItemCode`, or even `GROUP BY pInfo.ItemCode`) then it's all contained in one place.

Further, if you do ever add that column which Cory mentioned, any places in the query where you have used the ItemCode data are already optimised for the new structure you create.