# Handling multiple values in CASE statement?

Tags: t-sql

I have a scenario where I am trying to retrieve multiple values from a field/column based on a condition in a select statement. I was trying to use a Case Statement, but the problem is that the Case Statement does not support multiple values in a field/column. Is there any work around to this or any other way to achieve this?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, Period         
FROM   tblMonthlyCost

WHERE  Period = CASE

    WHEN Datepart(MONTH, Getdate()) = 8 
        AND Datediff(DAY, '07/31/2012', Getdate()) <= 3 THEN Period IN
            ('0112','0212','0312','0412','0512','0612') 
    WHEN Datepart(MONTH, Getdate()) = 8 
        AND Datediff(DAY, '07/31/2012', Getdate()) > 3 THEN Period IN
        ('0112','0212','0312','0412','0512','0612','0712')      
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to evaluate an input in the WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732423/how-to-evaluate-an-input-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CASE IN statement with multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449509/case-in-statement-with-multiple-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
SELECT  col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        Period
FROM    tblMonthlyCost
WHERE   Period IN ( '0112', '0212', '0312', '0412', '0512', '0612' )
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 8
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '07/31/2012', GETDATE()) <= 3
        OR Period IN ( '0112', '0212', '0312', '0412', '0512', '0612', '0712' )
        AND DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = 8
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, '07/31/2012', GETDATE()) > 3
```

Comment: You could factor out the common month 8 check and the common periods, i.e. other than `0712`.

Comment: agreed, I wasn't really trying to "fix" the query.  Just the logic questioned by the OP.

Comment: Dan's query fix was just what I needed and it worked great! The other suggestion will work fine in another query that i am developing.  thanks for both  answers.